# Cannot change QuickStyle in Qt 5.11

Tags: qt, styles

Hey I am using Qt Creator because there is no qml implementation in visual studio yet.

I am not able to change the style of quick components no matter what. I have tried it with global constants and as well as C++ API call but it still throws errors. I don't know what else to try.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQuickControls2/QQuickStyle>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickStyle::setStyle(QLatin1String("Material"));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

I stopped at this, I get these errors:

```
main.qml:6: error: Expected token `{'

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl QQuickStyle::setStyle(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setStyle@QQuickStyle@@SAXAEBVQString@@@Z) referenced in function main

debug\RandomGenerator.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I don't know what to do, there are no more tutorials explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this in qml.

enter this in **qtquickcontrols2.conf**

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Dark
```

If you want to change color or another properetys enter this in **main.qml** in *AplicationWindow*

```
Material.accent: Material.color(Material.Blue)
```

More info about styles and there properetys you can find [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html)